# C# adding reference problem

Tags: c#, selenium

I add selenium reference to the project and work ok but when i click rebuild project i get this error:

> ```
> Error 3   The type or namespace name 'Selenium' could not be found (are you
> ```
>
> missing a using directive or an
>   assembly
>   reference?)   D:\PROJEKTI\crawler\WebCrawlerSuite\NCrawler\Net
>   4.0\NCrawler.WinDemo\SeleniumHtmlDocumentProcessor.cs 6   7   NCrawler.WinDemo

and this warning:

> ```
> Warning   2   The referenced assembly "ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core" could not
> ```
>
> be resolved because it has a
>   dependency on "System.Web,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which
>   is not in the currently targeted
>   framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client".
>   Please remove references to assemblies
>   not in the targeted framework or
>   consider retargeting your
>   project.  NCrawler.WinDemo

what can be wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing this is because your project is using the Client Profile ("Profile=Client" in the framework version).  Try setting the target framework to plain old ".NET Framework 4" in your project properties and see if that does the trick.

In this case, the Selenium  assembly is referencing System.Web, which is not allowed for the Client profile framework.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx for details.